Ruzsa embedding lemma in $\mathbb{F}_p^N$
Below, you will find the lemma known as the Ruzsa embedding lemma in $\mathbb{F}_p^N$. I understood the idea of the proof quite well, but one technical detail is bothering me. I've pondered it for a while, but I'm still unable to grasp it. When we define $\Omega$, we notice that it depends on $n$, which is the codimension of $X$, and obviously $1 \leq n \leq N$. However, at the end of the proof, in order for the argument to hold, we choose $n$ to be the smallest natural number such that $p^n \geq C|A|$, i.e., $n = \lceil \log_p(C|A|)\rceil$. How do we know that $\lceil \log_p(C|A|)\rceil \in [1,N]$? Actually, I am not sure that this is true.
Update: Actually, I came across this result while watching Gowers' lectures on additive combinatorics. Here is the link

Lemma. Let $A$ be an additive set in $\mathbb{F}_p^N$ such that $|kA - kA| \leq C|A|$,
where $k \geq 1$ and $C \geq 1$. Then $A$ is Freiman $k$-isomorphic to
a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p^n$, where $n$ is the smallest natural number
such that $p^n \geq C|A|$.
Proof. The proof employs the probabilistic method. Consider the finite probability space $(\Omega, \mathbf{P})$ defined as follows:
$\Omega =\{X \leq \mathbb{F}_p^N \mid \dim(X) = N-n\}$ (where the
parameter $n \geq 1$ will be chosen later), and $\mathbf{P}:\Omega \to
 [0,1]$ is defined by $\mathbf{P}[X] = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}$ for every $X
 \in \Omega$. We observe that $|\Omega| = \binom{N}{N-n}_p$, where
$\binom{n}{k}_p$ is the Gaussian binomial coefficient.
For each $X\in \Omega$, let $q_X:\mathbb{F}_p^N\to \mathbb{F}_p^N/X$
be the quotient map defined by $v\mapsto v+X$. Since $q_X$ is a group
homomorphism, then $q_X :A\to q_X(A)$ is a surjective Freiman
homomorphism of order $k$. If $q_X:A\to q_X(A)$ is not a Freiman
$k$-isomorphism, then $\exists  a_1,\dots,a_k,a'_1,\dots,a'_k\in A$
such that $q_X(a_1)+\dots+q_X(a_k)=q_X(a'_1)+\dots+q_X(a'_k)$ and
$a_1+\dots+a_k\neq a'_1+\dots+a'_k$. Therefore, we have:
$$\{X\in \Omega: q_X:A\to q_X(A) \ \text{is not a
 $k$-isomorphism}\}\subset \bigcup_{\substack{z\in kA-kA \\ z\neq 0}}\{
 X\in \Omega: z\in X\}.$$
Hence we have:
$$\mathbf{P}[\{X\in \Omega: q_X:A\to q_X(A) \ \text{is not a
 $k$-isomorphism}\}]\leq \sum_{\substack{z\in kA-kA \\ z\neq
 0}}\mathbf{P}[\{ X\in \Omega: z\in X\}].$$
$$\mathbf{P}[\{ X\in \Omega: z\in
 X\}]=\dfrac{\binom{N-1}{N-n-1}_p}{\binom{N}{N-n}_p}=\dfrac{p^{N-n}-1}{p^N-1}<p^{-n}.$$
Therefore,
$$\mathbf{P}[\{X\in \Omega:  q_X:A\to q_X(A) \ \text{is not a
 $k$-isomorphism}\}]\leq\sum_{\substack{z\in kA-kA \\ z\neq 0}}p^{-n}<
 p^{-n}|kA-kA|.$$
Since $|kA-kA|\leq C|A|$, it follows that
$$\mathbf{P}[\{X\in \Omega:   q_X:A\to q_X(A) \ \text{is not a
 $k$-isomorphism}\}]<Cp^{-n}|A|.$$       Let $n$ be the smallest
natural number such that $p^n\geq C|A|$, i.e., $n=\lceil
 \log_p(C|A|)\rceil$. Then $$\mathbf{P}[\{X\in \Omega:    q_X:A\to
 q_X(A) \ \text{is not a $k$-isomorphism}\}]<1.$$
Hence there exists $X\in \Omega$
such that $q_X:A\to q_X(A)$ is a $k$-isomorphism. Note that
$q_X(A)\subset \mathbb{F}_p^N/X$ and
$\dim(\mathbb{F}_p^N/X)=N-(N-n)=n$, and hence $\mathbb{F}_p^N/X\cong
 \mathbb{F}_p^n$. Therefore, $A$ is $k$-isomorphic to a subset of
$\mathbb{F}_p^n$.


It may appear that $n>N$, but then there is nothing to prove

@FedorPetrov, I am a bit confused by your comment. If $n > N$, the proof simply fails because $\Omega$ does not make sense. So what do you mean by "there is nothing to prove"? Maybe your point is just to take $f:A\to A\times{0}^{n-N}$ which is obviously a Freiman $k$-isomorphism.

Yes, my point is that the statement holds trivially in this case

@FedorPetrov, yeah but in that scenario we don't even use the fact that $|kA-kA|\leq C|A|$. So I belive that $n$ should be smaller than $N$.

Ok, we do not use, but we have no obligation to use it in all cases.

While $C$ can be arbitrarily large, note that $|k A - k A| \leq p^N$, so there's never a point to take it such that $C |A| > p^N$.

@FedorPetrov, it seems that I did not understand your point correctly yesterday. My bad. So your point basically was: 1) If $n > N$, then there is nothing to prove. 2) If $n \leq N$, then the proof which I provided works.

@CommandMaster, I am very confused by your comment. Can you please provide more details to explain it?

@RFZ yes, exactly

@FedorPetrov, Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it!
